# How to execute Gradle task more than once?

Tags: gradle

I've got custom tasks in `build.gradle` file. I need to periodically recompile sources. The idea is to call `tasks.compileJava.execute()` in infinite looping custom task. The problem is that (as I understand) task will be executed only once (it doesn't depends on task type/inputs/outputs - even custom tasks will be executed only once).

How can I force gradle to execute task more than once (check inputs/outputs and mark it as `UP-TO-DATE` if it make sence)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task cannot be executed more than once, and `Task.execute()` should never be called from user code (not even once). Continuous task execution is a planned feature and will require changes to the Gradle codebase.